# React Router Browser Router with hash fragments combined?

Tags: react-router-dom

We're using react router v6 in a project, and have a potential need to store some search results filter fields in the hash fragments of the url, i.e.

/search#fn=Bob&sn=Smith&expanded=12088&active=1

I'm wondering, is there any way to do this in react router, or do I have to roll some kind of utility to generate links and then rely on vanilla js or something to read the hash fragments of the current route in react router and would I have to manually compute the links to navigate to?

So right now /search is an object based Route, and what I really want to do is be able to specify parameters that can be passed to that route via hash fragments so that when I use something like the useParams hook I can see them?

I really want to make all the search criteria deep linkable but I don't really want to have a route like "/search/Bob/Smith/expanded/1208" or some craziness like that.

Or maybe the answer is to do something janky like this?

```
/search/fn=Bob&ln=Smith&expanded=12088&active=1
```

Comment: Why not just use querystring? `/search?fn=Bob&sn=Smith&expanded=12088&active=1`

Comment: The app is an SPA and you can't update a query string without a hard page refresh.  Our app has zero hard page refreshes, once loaded it's loaded and you zip around.  All of our navigation happens in react router v6 with no page loads, it just changes what components are in view.  We make heavy use of routes, child routes, and outlets to drive layout changes.  Unless I can update the query string without a page refresh, correct me If I'm wrong.  That didn't use to be a thing but I could be out of touch a little.

Comment: I guess. Are you just looking for the [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter) then? React-router-dom is all client side, AFAIK, it's just manipulating the address bar for the most part.

Comment: I updated my comment, no I don't want to go to hash router entirely.  I guess I'm just trying to figure out the proper way to put search params in a url in react router.  If I can do a query string without causing refreshes then i can go look at that.

Comment: Looks like you can... didn't think that was possible, must have been recent in the last couple years of browser updates or I'm just a dinosaur.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the HashRouter (or hash routing) and using the hash part of the link, but it's on the [location](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#locationhash) object so surely it's available in RRDv6 and used for *something*.

Comment: Turns out I can update the query string without causing a refresh because of the history hook etc, and as such I can use the "useSearchParams" hook to get the searchParams used on a route.  So no need for me to touch location object etc.

I can just call "useSearchParams" on the component on the /search route and it'll have every query param key/value pair on it that the route has in the url.

I'll either answer this myself or delete this lol.  Unless you want to answer it and I'll accept it, cuz you were kind of right Drew Reese

Comment: Oh, I was more referring to the fact that it's on the `location` object that you can use it in links, and access via the `useLocation` hook. Sounds like you have what you need figured out though. Good luck.

Comment: Updated my previous comment, but yeah you were basically right, I can use query params and useSearchParams to get what I want.

Comment: Na, no worries, I was just spit-balling to be honest... I'd never seen the hash used like that to store "state"... it's interesting.

Comment: I did it eons ago when you couldn't change a query string without a refresh and I had to support IE 11, it's how I solved for it on an old knockout SPA from like 2016, but seems to no longer be a problem with history state being mainstream now and IE11 being dead for us here. It was a hack from the get go :)